# Verb after "would you mind..?"

Tags: grammar

Would you mind **to explain** **to me** why didn't show up last night?

If I correct above sentence like the sentences below, I 'm not sure which one is okay.

Would you mind **explaining** **to me** why didn't show up last night?

Would you mind **explaining** **me** why didn't show up last night?

Kindly help, thank you so much!

Comment: In this case, the reason you didn't show up last night is the direct object.  (Why you didn't show up last night is an informal way of saying the reason that you didn't show up lsat night.)  Therefore, "me" is an indirect object.  So, "would you mind explaining the reason to me" probably sounds clearer to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Mind" is followed by an "-ing" form when it is followed by a verb. This is a strict rule.
So we must proceed like this:

> Would you mind having...?

"Explain" works like this: explain something **to** somebody.

> Can you explain the rules to me?

Now we have to combine the two rules, remembering "mind" needs a verb in present participle, and "explain" needs "to + person":

> Would you mind explaining to me why you didn't show up last night?

Is the winner. The way we link verbs to other verbs, or use them with objects is commonly called [Verb Patterns](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode30/languagepoint.shtml)). Take a look at the basic article linked before which summarises the different types.

Comment: +1 for the Verb Pattern link. This is so useful. I always wanted it!

Comment: No worries. I'm sure there are plenty more on the Internet. FYI: There are 5 Verb Patterns. I recommend learning 5 (common) verbs for each pattern to get you used to using them.

Comment: Indeed. Consider it *done*. I'm sincere ;)

Comment: Got stuck! The verb 'think' takes **Verb + preposition + verb +ing** as its pattern. What about *I'm thinking to propose her this Valentines Day.*; *I'm thinking to bring him here tonight* sounds better than *I'm thinking to proposing... or I'm thinking to bringing ....*

Comment: No! "Think to + verb" is a very rare construction! The most common form for "think" is "think of doing" or "think about doing". Read up on the difference between "of" and "about" for the finer points. Example 1 should be: I'm thinking of proposing to her this Valentine's Day."

Comment: And what about its past tense? *I thought to propose...* Does *think* there takes 'to'?

Comment: Nope. "I thought about proposing... = I considered proposing". "Think to" as a general rule, only exists in the past: "He never thought to check out the identity of the supposed salesman".